# dplyr like %>% syntax in julia

Tags: julia, dplyr

In R (thanks to `magrittr`/`dplyr`) you can now call functions without brackets but you can pipe them along instead.

This means that instead of coding this:

```
> as.character((sqrt(12)^2)
> as.Date("2014-01-01")
```

You could also do this:

```
> 12 %>% sqrt %>% .^2 %>% as.character
> "2014-01-01" %>% as.Date
```

R uses this extensively to edit dataframes. Beyond dataframes, I feel that this syntax is very readable and powerful for creating functional scripts.

Does the julia language have support for something similar?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, in two senses.

So first of all there is `|>`, e.g.

```
12 |> sqrt |> x->x^2 |> string  # 11.999999999999998
using Dates  # needed in 0.3, baked in to 0.4
"2014-01-1" |> d->Date(d,"yyyy-mm-dd") |> year |> iseven  # true
```

I wouldn't say its very idiomatic Julia though (or R, which the exception of doing operations on a dataframe with `dplyr`). [There is a discussion about enhancing this type of thing and making the syntax better.](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/5571) You can do a lot of neat things with [Lazy.jl](https://github.com/one-more-minute/Lazy.jl) right now though!

For DataFrames in particular, its a WIP, but there is [DataFramesMeta.jl](https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataFramesMeta.jl) combined with [Lazy.jl](https://github.com/one-more-minute/Lazy.jl), which lets you do things like `dplyr` and `LINQ` such as (taken from their README):

```
x_thread = @> begin
    df
    @transform(y = 10 * :x)
    @where(:a .> 2)
    @by(:b, meanX = mean(:x), meanY = mean(:y))
    @orderby(:meanX)
    @select(:meanX, :meanY, var = :b)
end
```